# Extract graphics symbol name in a delayed function?

Tags: graphics, function-construction

Here's a simple "save as image" function:

```
saveImage[image_Graphics, format_String: "png", resolution_Real: 200] := Export[
   TemplateApply[
     "`basename`.`format`", <|
     "basename" -> SymbolName[Unevaluated[image]],
     "format" -> format|
     >]
   , image
   , ImageResolution -> resolution
   ];
```

However, I can't make it hold the image name:

```
myImage = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]

saveImage@myImage (* evaluates image to be a Graphics object instead of the symbol *)
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Take a look at `HoldFirst` but then you need to change `image_Graphics` as you expect `_Symbol`.

Comment: @Kuba: indeed this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Unevaluated`, `saveImage` must be held when calling `saveImage`. So I give `saveImage` the attribute `HoldFirst`. From now on, pattern matching won't work anymore for the first argument. That's why I added `/; Head[image] === Graphics` at the end.

Try this instead:

```
ClearAll[saveImage];
SetAttributes[saveImage, HoldFirst];
saveImage[image_, format_String: "png", resolution_Real: 200] := 
  Export[TemplateApply[
     "`basename`.`format`", <|
      "basename" -> SymbolName[Unevaluated[image]], 
      "format" -> format|>
     ]
       , image
       , ImageResolution -> resolution
    ] /; Head[image] === Graphics;
```